# android mobile application automatic passkey entry "SMP protocol"

Tags: java, android

I'm an embedd system engineer & I'm not a mobile application developer, I'm working in a project, something like ble beacons, I want my connection between the mobile app & the beacon to be secure as much as possible.

I added a passkey to the beacon & the mobile application should first send the passkey then complete the connection.

----> My question is the android mobile application can send the passkey automatically without any pop up notification asking to enter the passkey ? ?

I mean can I hardcode the passkey in the mobile application or this process must be handled by the mobile itself not the mobile application.

----> also can the mobile application remember the beacon & when it disconnect then re-connect remember the beacon's passkey and enter it without any user interface in that case ? ?

thanks for your great help :) :)

Comment: You're free to hardcode the keys for the first prototype :)

But it's up to the driver (bluez or bluedroid) to handle pairing/unpairing/re-pairing of all Bluetooth devices.

Comment: yes, I was asking about that, its possible that the passkey entry process can be automatic with no user interface, the mobile app is responsible to handle that.. is it okay ? ?

Comment: For your last question, there is flag which you can handle on com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED

Comment: I ddn't understand your answer? ? ? VVB